# How to perform integration testing in Spring Boot with Gemfire and multiple Spring Application Configurations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, gemfire

I'm trying to run an integration test that has a different `SpringApplicationConfiguration` from the other integration tests. The issue only manifests when Gemfire is configured.

A demonstration of the error in available here: https://github.com/kemitix/test-spring-boot-gemfire-testing

There are two test classes `ContextsApplicationTests` and `ContextsApplicationWithCustomTests`.

The first uses a standard `SpringApplicationConfiguration` based on the `ContextsApplication` class. The other attempts to also include the `CustomConfiguration` class to override a Bean.

Test one:

```
@IntegrationTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ContextsApplication.class)
public class ContextsApplicationTests {
...
```

Test two:

```
@IntegrationTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
    ContextsApplication.class,
    CustomConfiguration.class
})
public class ContextsApplicationWithCustomTests {
```

Without having Gemfire enabled the tests run happily.

However, having Gemfire configured causes an issue with the context loader throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    a beanFactoryReference already exists for key cacheFactoryBean
```

The full output is included in the file `mvn-clean-install.txt` in the repo.

When the two tests are run in isolation they work. It is only when they are run together that the issue appears. I suspect the Gemfire instance that Spring Boot is running is causing some sort of bleed-over between the two tests that is causing the Contexts not to be properly segregated. Unfortunately, I've no idea how to influence this.

Comment: I've found that I can workround this by adding `@DirtiesContext` to the `ContextsApplicationWithCustomTests` class. However, in my use-case that configuration applies to all but one test. The exception is the test that doesn't use the `CustomConfiguration`.  Using `@DirtiesContext` on `ContextsApplicationTests` doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try CacheFactoryBean.setUseBeanFactoryLocator(false)

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.

`@Bean
CacheFactoryBean cacheFactoryBean() {
    final CacheFactoryBean cacheFactoryBean = new CacheFactoryBean();
    cacheFactoryBean.setUseBeanFactoryLocator(false);
    return cacheFactoryBean;
}`